# Saving Postman environment variables not working correctly?

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I'm experiencing a strange thing when exporting environment variables in my test and pre-request scripts. Let's take the following code:

```
var temp = ["a", "b", "c"];
pm.environment.set("Array1", temp);
temp.length=0;
temp = ["1", "2", "3"];
pm.environment.set("Array2", temp);
temp.length=0;
temp = ["ZZ", "YY", "XX"];
pm.environment.set("Array3", temp);
console.log(pm.environment.get("Array1")); // expected = ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(pm.environment.get("Array2")); // expected = ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(pm.environment.get("Array3")); // expected = ["ZZ", "YY", "XX"]
```

I'm expecting all 3 arrays to have value right? Surprisingly the results are:

```
[]
[]
["ZZ", "YY", "XX"]
```

Only the last one is correct. And I can carry on with more arrays, everytime, only the last one gets really updated, all the other ones remain desperately empty. I don't understand what's wrong. Beside, I tried postman.setEnvironmentVariable instead of pm.environment.set and it worked find. Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this isn't really a Postman question. It's a question about Javascript. I don't know anything about Postman but its `pm.environment.set()` method is obviously saving a reference to the array object rather than making a copy. When you subsequently do `temp.length = 0;` you truncate that array object so that it has zero elements. When you subsequently do `temp = ['new', 'array'];` you're creating a new array object and assigning a reference to it to the `temp` var. You then pass that new array object reference to the next `pm.environment.set()`. Note that the `temp.length = 0;` statement is unnecessary and the source of your problem.

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

P.S., I'm curious what documentation you read that implied doing `temp.length = 0;` was the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm very very noobish in JS as you noticed :) Actually I  thought it was more secure to erase an array variable before reusing it. That's why I set its length to 0. Your explaination made it really clear for me now. I understand better the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @user12845915 I'm glad you found my answer helpful. Could you please mark it as answering your question?